# Python - I zip some folders with subfolders but it zips twice.

Tags: python, file, zip

I have written a script. It finds the current path and changes the path and zips. Then I want that it just find the zip file copy it to another directory and at the end removes the content of the folder. But it zips once and zips again the whole folders and zip-file. The intial situation is as in Figure 1.
[image: Initial directroy-tree]

The script is like this:

```
import os
import zipfile
import shutil
import glob

Pfad = os.getcwd()
newPfad = 'D'+ Pfad[1:]
Zip_name=os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(Pfad))
shutil.make_archive(Zip_name, 'zip', Pfad)

if not os.path.exists(newPfad):
    os.makedirs(newPfad)

dest_dir=newPfad
files = glob.iglob(os.path.join(Pfad, "*.zip"))
for file in files:
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        shutil.copy2(file, dest_dir)

shutil.rmtree(Pfad)
```

And finally the result is illustrated in the following figure.

[image: After Execution]

The batch file is just for running the python script.

How can I get the following desired situation?

[image]

Comment: You're packing the whole current dir into the zip file (stored also in the current  dir). Next time you run your script the archive will be there and it will be packed too. You should `shutil.move` instead of `shutil.copy2`. As a note, your last line removes the current dir, which might yield unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that zip file is created prior to listing the directory contents, therefore empty zip file is added to. Create archive in the parent directory and then move it. Moving a file or directory is cheap and atomic.

```
import os
import shutil

cwd = os.path.abspath(os.path.curdir)
zip_target = os.path.join(cwd, os.path.basename(cwd)) + '.zip'
zip_source = shutil.make_archive(cwd, 'zip')
os.rename(zip_source, zip_target)
```